# GGeffects not computing confidence intervals

Tags: r

I previously posted this question but suspect my example made things difficult to reproduce. My data set involves participants making ratings under different conditions basically. Here is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(subject = c("608e875414e027cb3b277df1", "5c636176bad3560001c27467", 
"5df58b28ecb3ea3ed1ceea37", "5eeaa065c7acf61c4322f6d9", "5ef90b249bafa50a311593ae", 
"5e5323c8c9f6063449ad9f00", "5f10db021500352a6cf465eb", "5b32c0ff975e260001e97d0e", 
"607f1f1b945e95af870d0dec", "610455c1ee6fdb0b18a4bcf2", "60ff12387f5a68f7f0eef74c", 
"5f6c102b6ec04317fc9a8127", "5ee0c244c68c754255de45dc", "5f9b014daee4da2af5391e54", 
"5e7f514bb18cb4000a68310d", "5f4b58fe934d640114964f93", "60ad2a94807ae7448c627404", 
"60dfe3a5dc15b57d55fd14b1", "5ef90b249bafa50a311593ae", "60382d89160c3e15cc2cb369", 
"5f935494c542c2119a47e3c4", "5e974eb244b6d01f4117d2fa", "5dc797a6a4cc4255f8ea588e", 
"5eaef287fb863f5c922abad9", "6296267b2ae249a205d319d3"), condition = c("odd", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "odd", "odd", "odd", "mean", "odd", "odd", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", 
"mean", "odd", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "odd"), rating = c(4, 
4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 
4, 5, 3), image = c("grilled_cheese_01", "soup_02", "tomato_mozzarella_01", 
"asian_03", "bike_02", "cake3", "asian_04", "apple_01", "soup_01", 
"cookie5", "chicken_2", "tomato_mozzarella_01", "asian_01", "guitar_3", 
"candy_3", "chips_03", "drums_3", "ice_skates_02", "paper_2", 
"microscope_2", "bagel_1", "bun_1", "tomato_mozzarella_01", "tennis_03", 
"veggie_01"), trial = c(22L, 14L, 60L, 34L, 24L, 25L, 34L, 8L, 
18L, 54L, 10L, 33L, 43L, 25L, 32L, 49L, 48L, 34L, 13L, 23L, 8L, 
36L, 55L, 3L, 52L), PE = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0), learn_prof = c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(17347L, 1434L, 3238L, 
6367L, 13582L, 3872L, 7208L, 12123L, 17273L, 20211L, 19845L, 
15358L, 6125L, 16029L, 4598L, 8446L, 18058L, 11594L, 13653L, 
11479L, 15731L, 13227L, 2878L, 13557L, 21959L), class = "data.frame")
```

My model (below) assesses the effect of condition, learning, profile, and trial on prediction errors with random effects for subject and image.

```
TD_PE_analysis <- lmer(PE ~  learn_prof * trial * condition + (1|subject) + (1|image), data=td_pref_all)
```

When I run the model with the full data set, I get the following results:

```
Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    4.948e-01  9.227e-02  8.601e+02   5.363 1.05e-07 ***
learn_prof                     7.675e-01  5.074e-02  9.678e+02  15.125  < 2e-16 ***
trial                          1.437e-03  1.829e-03  2.169e+04   0.786  0.43193    
conditionodd                   2.260e-01  1.118e-01  9.010e+02   2.022  0.04347 *  
learn_prof:trial              -3.733e-03  1.163e-03  2.168e+04  -3.211  0.00132 ** 
learn_prof:conditionodd       -1.385e-01  5.765e-02  2.168e+04  -2.402  0.01631 *  
trial:conditionodd            -3.060e-03  2.581e-03  2.168e+04  -1.185  0.23590    
learn_prof:trial:conditionodd  1.906e-03  1.643e-03  2.168e+04   1.160  0.24589    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) lrn_pr trial  cndtnd lrn_prf:t lrn_prf:c trl:cn
learn_prof  -0.820                                                
trial       -0.606  0.664                                         
conditiondd -0.607  0.438  0.501                                  
lrn_prf:trl  0.575 -0.700 -0.948 -0.474                           
lrn_prf:cnd  0.467 -0.568 -0.585 -0.769  0.616                    
trl:cndtndd  0.430 -0.471 -0.709 -0.706  0.672     0.826          
lrn_prf:tr: -0.407  0.495  0.671  0.669 -0.708    -0.871    -0.948
```

So, at this point everything is working as expected, however when I go to try and visualize my model with the following code `TD_plot <- ggpredict(TD_PE_analysis, terms = c("trial", "learn_prof"))` I receive a warning saying R cannot compute a variance-covariance matrix and thus no confidence intervals can be returned. I will need confidence intervals on my plot so I'm not sure why this is happening. That said, when I add "condition" back into the terms in ggpredict it does compute confidence intervals. Why is R unable to compute the variance/covariance matrix? I can't seem to find any good reason this is breaking down.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I needed to simplify my model before plotting. Thus, I had to make a second model with *just* learning profile and trial for confidence intervals to be computed

Comment: But you were getting the var-covar matrix? I'm getting the same error and I'm not sure how to properly solve this problem as well without simplifying the model...